# How to make search work in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have the following code which works fine.. I wan to add a search functionality... Can you please tell me what should I do and where

MyDatabase.java

```
package com.example.test4;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyDatabase {
    public static final String MY_DB2 = "testdb5";
    MyHelper mh;
    Context myCon;
    SQLiteDatabase sdb;

    public MyDatabase(Context c) {
        myCon = c;
        mh = new MyHelper(myCon, MY_DB2, null, 1);
    }

    public void open() {
        sdb = mh.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public MyHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
                int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("create table students(_id integer primary key, "
                    + "s_name text, " + "s_attendance text, "
                    + "s_homework text, " + "s_participation text, "
                    + "s_quiz integer, " + "s_test integer, "
                    + "s_comment text, " + "p_email text);");
            Log.d("1", "Table Created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    public void StudentsInsert(ContentValues cv) {
        sdb.insert("students", null, cv);
    }

    public Cursor getStudents() {
        Cursor c = sdb.query("students", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        return c;
    }

    public Cursor filterStudents() {
        // SQLiteDatabase db = mh.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor c = sdb.query("students", new String[] { "s_name",
                "s_attendance", "s_homework", "s_participation", "s_quiz",
                "s_test", "s_comment", "p_email" }, "s_name like %a%", null,
                null, null, null);
        return c;

    }

}
```

I think I am doing something wrong in filterStudents()...

and this is what I have on other file

```
EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
        myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         }

         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
           int count, int after) {
         }

         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
           int before, int count) {
          sca.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
         }
        });

        sca.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
               public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                   return mdb.filterStudents();
               }
           });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem.. I would like to share this..

my Code looks like this

```
EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
        myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         }

         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
           int count, int after) {
         }

         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
           int before, int count) {
          sca.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
         }
        });

        sca.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
               public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                   return mdb.fetchMyValues(constraint.toString());
               }
           });
```

and on my database file I added the following code

```
public Cursor fetchMyValues(String inputText) {

        String DATABASE_TABLE="students";
        return sdb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {"_id", "s_name",
                "s_attendance", "s_homework", "s_participation", "s_quiz",
                "s_test", "s_comment", "p_email"}, 
                  "s_name like '%" + inputText +"%'"  , null, null, null, null);}
```

now my search works good...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try putting quotes around the filter string.  ie, instead of:

```
like %a%
```

Make it:

```
like '%a%'
```

Keep your doublequotes (") the way they are, but add single quotes around the filter string.

Comment: oh, not changing the quotes.  ADDING to the quotes.  Inside your double-quotes you had:  like %a%  I wanted you to change it to:  like '%a%'.  Which, ultimately, is what you did.

Comment: actually I didn't change it.. I added it.. the program crashed when I did that... anyway thank you for trying

Answer (score 0):

I am using this way may be helpful for you.

Create adapter for setting data in to listview.

Create listview for displaying data.

```
myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {         
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){                                
      myadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
      listview.setAdapter(myadapter);    
      myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}

MyDatabase mdb = new MyDatabase(this);
//set adapter as per requirement this is sample.
myadapter= new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_search, m_curContacts, fields, new int []{R.id.textView1,R.id.imageView1});
    myadapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {            
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        //check here cursor is getting any result or not.if not then problem with your query.   
            return mdb.filterStudents();
    }

});
```

You have to used `"'%"+ value+ "%'"` this way in database.

Comment: Thank you for your post, but still I am not to get it to work!
Do you want me to put the complete code as I put for Database.java?

Comment: MyDatabase mdb = new MyDatabase(this); --> gives me an error at (;) red underline
        
myadapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider()---> on this line is other error

Comment: I will later... and I will inform you..  have a meeting now